# Display slidingUpPanel across all activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I'm trying to add a slidingUpPanel([Sliding up panel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)) across all activities. This panel consists of a viewpager which in turn consists of two fragments. One of these fragments has a recyclerView (more than 1000 items) and the other fragment has some data that changes dynamically depending on the users' choice. This panel is very similar to that of google play music and soundcloud. Now to display this panel I tested two approaches:

1) I created a base activity and added the sliding up panel to it and then extended rest of the activities to base activity. So this way I have to create only one panel and viewpager.

2) I included the sliding up panel in all activities. But this approach is quite unmanageable as I have create viewpagers for all activities and if data changes in one activity I have to write the code to reflect that change across all activities.

Now the problem with both the methods is that each time I open a new activity, a new instance of the viewpager and fragments is created. So, suppose if I have 1000+ items in the recyclerview fragment, switching activities takes more than 2-3 seconds, because each time new instance of fragment is created and the data is loaded all again. This will definitely result in bad user experience.

Is there any way by which the viewpager and the fragments are created only once(when the app starts) and are destroyed only when user closes the app? And data should not load each time user switches activities. I just want to reduce the activity switching time. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Try creating one activity for, with the viewpager, and place other activities as fragments within that activity.

Comment: Didn't get you. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: 1000+ items in the recyclerview  => that's your issue, how is that practical for the user ?

Comment: If the user has 1000+ songs in his/her device, all will be listed here. And this list of songs is stored in sharedpreference. Not tried lazy loading as I have seen no offline music player apps that implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for such ui elements as your sliding panel, which stays the same for many items it is preferable to have a single activity.

So if you have 1 activity, you can have a viewpager inside sliding panel, and that part stays untouched. Next, inside your activity you can have FrameLayout wich can be used to host fragments. Doing this you can achieve single instance of sliding panel and navigation between content with fragments.

Having some heavy data collections makes you wishing minimum recreation of that items.

Comment: So you are trying to say that, I create a single activity and add the sliding up panel and viewpager to it along with Framelayout. And then, convert the activities that I have right now into fragments and add them to this activity(framelayout). Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly, this will allow you to have all global logic inside activity, and all separate screens within fragments

Comment: The solution is good, but I have 9-10 activities and I don't think it is feasible for me to edit them all :(

Comment: Well, this is the only thing you can have one instance of panel, also creation of fragment takes less resources than creation of an activity

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches for this are (assuming you're using SlidingUpPanelLayout by sothree)

- **With bottom navigation view**
  Easy way to do it is creating a bottom navigation view and keeping it in MainActivity and attaching the sliding up panel layout to the bottom navigation view ( `layout_above = bottomnavbar_id` ) since bottom navigation stays throughout the app so sliding up panel will also have to stay with it
- **Without bottom navigation view**
  Create a frame layout inside MainActivity give attributes width and height as `match_parent` and create slidinguppanelayout and give attributes `gravity="bottom"`
  make the frame layout stay above that slidinguppanellayout , use that `frame_layout` to show content your want to show from fragments

that's all